# Undefined index when editing default language value in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to get the multi language feature in Backpack working. I've followed all steps that are present in the documentation. I am able to add the values in the languages I've defined. I can also edit these values except for the default language. I'm getting an undefined index 'nl' error.

The defined languages are following: nl (Dutch), fr (French), en (English).

I've tried changing my default language and see how the applications reacts to it but I'm facing the same issue on the main (defined in config/app.php) language.

I've also downgraded laravel-translatable to v 3.x as the Backpack changelog doesn't mention any support to the v 4.x of that package. Now I'm back on the v4 as it made no difference.

Currently in my composer file I have this:
"backpack/base": "^0.9.7",
"backpack/crud": "^3.3.0",
"backpack/permissionmanager": "^2.1",
"backpack/settings": "^2.0",
"intervention/image": "^2.4",
"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
"spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.0"

My crud config:

```
    'show_translatable_field_icon' => true,
    'translatable_field_icon_position' => 'right',

    'locales' => [
        'nl',
        'fr',
        'en'
    ],
```

The mode I want to apply translations to:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;
use Backpack\CRUD\ModelTraits\SpatieTranslatable\HasTranslations;

class Supplier extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasTranslations;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'suppliers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    protected $translatable =  ['name'];
```

A value in my table looks like this:
{"nl":"Leverancier x nl","1":"Leverancier x fr"}

I need to also be able to edit the default language. As for now I don't see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting and the stack trace for it?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone encounters the same issue...
Fairly logic this didn't work.

You should declare locals like this:

```
'locales' => [
    'nl' => 'Dutch',
    'fr' => 'French',
    'en' => 'English'
],
```